# How to resize a D3D11Texture2D?

Tags: 2d, textures, directx11, gpu

I would like to scale a D3D11Texture2D to make it smaller.

I'm using AcquireNextFrame to get an output of my desktop but it's on FullHD resolution. I just want to scale the texture because I need then to send the buffer over network.

Here is my code :

```
if (mRealTexture == nullptr) {
        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC description;
        texture2D->GetDesc(&description);
        description.BindFlags = 0;
        description.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
        description.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
        description.MiscFlags = 0;
        hr = mDevice->CreateTexture2D(&description, NULL, &mRealTexture);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            if (mRealTexture) {
                mRealTexture->Release();
                mRealTexture = nullptr;
            }
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    mImmediateContext->CopyResource(mRealTexture, texture2D);

    if (mScaledTexture == nullptr) {
        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC description;
        texture2D->GetDesc(&description);
        description.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
        description.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
        description.Width = 1440;
        description.Height = 585;
        description.MipLevels = 4;
        description.ArraySize = 1;
        description.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        description.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
        description.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        hr = mDevice->CreateTexture2D(&description, NULL, &mScaledTexture);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            if (mScaledTexture) {
                mScaledTexture->Release();
                mScaledTexture = nullptr;
            }
            return NULL;
        }
    } //How to copy the mRealTexture to the mScaledTexture and get the new buffer ?

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mapped;
    hr = mImmediateContext->Map(mRealTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE, 0, &mapped);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        mRealTexture->Release();
        mRealTexture = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }
    unsigned char *source = static_cast<unsigned char *>(mapped.pData);
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

CopyResource does not support scaling.

Mapping would work, but:

1. You would need to write your own scaling algorithm
2. You would need to download the data from GPU to system memory before scaling,
3. You would need to re-upload the data back to the GPU after scaling.

Two ways spring to mind.

**One**

Create the texture with D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET, use [ID3D11DeviceContext::GenerateMips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476426(v=vs.85).aspx), then send one of the miplevels; miplevel 0 is the full resolution texture, miplevel 1 is half resolution in each dimension, miplevel 2 is quarter resolution in each dimension, etc.

**Two**

Draw the texture to a lower-resolution rendertarget, then use that rendertarget instead of the original source texture.

Comment: So is it possible to scale a buffer of pixel (1920x1080) to (1280x720) if it's the only way..? I got the buffer of data with mapping.

Comment: In terms of performance, if I want to scale down by 2x, is generating mipmaps is faster than rendering to a lower resolution target?

Comment: @Jack - nowadays you'd probably do it in a compute shader.  "In terms of performance" is hugely dependent on what other work your program is doing, whether rendertarget changes have impact or can be interleaved with other work, whether you need access to the scaled down data in the same frame or can wait until one or two frames later, whether you need it on the CPU or it can stay on the GPU, etc.  If you have something specific in mind then you're better off asking it as a separate question.